# How to correctly list index values of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Each time I run this line of code, my index values increase.  The first time I run the code my index values are (0, 1, 2) then the next time I run it during the same testing I get values of (3, 4, 5) for the same array elements.

```
System.out.println("**********The Book List**********");
for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) { 
    System.out.print("Index: " + index++);
    System.out.print("\t");
    System.out.print("Name: " + books.get(i));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And where in your code do you set `index` back to `0`?

Comment: you write `index++`, never reset it, what do you expect?

Comment: i an index. wait what are you trying to achieve? tell us why it shouldn't increase?

Comment: Why not print `i` as the index?

Answer (score 2):

You use `books.get(i)` in the loop, so it appears that `i` is the `index` you're after. Like,

```
System.out.print("Index: " + i);
```

And then remove `index`.